# PushNotification error ecb method not defined

Tags: cordova, push-notification, phonegap-plugins, google-cloud-messaging, phonegap-pushplugin

Somehow I cant make the Google Server call my function defined in ecb.
It always throws an error like this:
processMessage failed: Message: `"Javascript:services.onNotificationGCM({"regid":"APA91bFYQ0BJcTcHCBGM0ipQZ0qAbsZUQK-EW0BIrF-Tl-dB_H7GAxHGhHXcxYUvrzykg9jVChZIEPRSpgtIYj02EwpwofukxdImIKFharjihIQ2tgEWOnDJrP6WX7ZJ0j1G8ldJllPMTPR155Pyx9PGT1eWm0zYzw","event":"registered"})"`

My code

```
var services = angular.module('services', [])
services.factory('services', function() {
    var bgGeo;
    return {
        enablePushNotification: function() {
            document.addEventListener("deviceready", function() {
                var pushNotification = window.plugins.pushNotification
                    .register(function(result) {
                        alert(
                            'Callback Success! Result = ' +
                            result)
                    }, function(error) {
                        alert("ErrorHandler");
                        alert(error);
                    }, {
                        "senderID": "168615009802",
                        "ecb": "services.onNotificationGCM"
                    });
            }, false)
        },
        onNotificationGCM: function(e) {
            alert("onNotification extra factory")
        }
    }
})
```

I have literally tried everything, so I hope you can help me!
Thanks! :)

Comment: how does your log look like other than this line? any other inconsistency?